# how to swf file convert gif format with onmouse over and onmouse out

Tags: gif, swf

Hi i am created flash file moving image when i click on the image running stop muse out running continuously. same i converted gif format but on mouse click and on mouse over not working pls give me suggestion

Comment: Gif don't have "onmouse events". You need to set the event in html and jquery like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294999/play-pause-gif-with-mouse-event

Answer (score 3):

You can't export directly from Animate / Flash to GIF and retain script effects. Mouse hover events will also not be exported - GIF files don't support interaction.

Your best bet would be to rebuild it with HTML and javascript. Check out the answer provided in SZCZERZO KŁY's comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294999/play-pause-gif-with-mouse-event

Comment: This answer falls on the realm of a link only answer.  While the link **may** provide guidance to the question the parts that do answer the question should be referenced here.  This helps make a quality Q&A.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ My answer is: you can't do it with flash, needs to be done in HTML+JS. Maybe too short, but there are tons of tutorials on HTML/JS and there's that other answer already.